# REST form (like form_for in Ruby) for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, pug

I have a form for adding videos to the database. I would like to use the same form for editing the videos or creating a new one. In ruby this is easy using scaffolds. But how would I achieve the same thing with NodeJS? (Using Jade as well, if possible)

So when the form is used to edit a video it populates the form with the current values, otherwise it shows them all blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap the [forms-bootstrap](https://github.com/marni/forms-bootstrap) module works well